# gettext binary MO file creating with Java

Tags: java, gettext

I tried creating a utility to parse gettext po file and generate binary mo file. The parser is simple (my co. not use fuzzy, plural, etc. things, just msgid/msgstr), but the generator is not work.

Here is [the description of the mo file](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html#MO-Files), here is [the original generator source](http://cvs.savannah.gnu.org/viewvc/gettext/gettext-tools/src/msgfmt.c?root=gettext&view=markup) (it's C), and found a php script (https://github.com/josscrowcroft/php.mo/blob/master/php-mo.php) also.

My code:

```
public void writeFile(String filename, Map<String, String> polines) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

  DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filename));
  HashMap<String, String> bvc = new HashMap<String, String>();
  TreeMap<String, String> hash = new TreeMap(bvc);
  hash.putAll(polines);


  StringBuilder ids = new StringBuilder();
  StringBuilder strings = new StringBuilder();
  ArrayList<ArrayList> offsets = new ArrayList<ArrayList>();
  ArrayList<Integer> key_offsets = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  ArrayList<Integer> value_offsets = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  ArrayList<Integer> temp_offsets = new ArrayList<Integer>();

  for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : hash.entrySet()) {
    String id = entry.getKey();
    String str = entry.getValue();

    ArrayList<Integer> offsetsItems = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    offsetsItems.add(ids.length());
    offsetsItems.add(id.length());
    offsetsItems.add(strings.length());
    offsetsItems.add(str.length());
    offsets.add((ArrayList) offsetsItems.clone());

    ids.append(id).append('\0');
    strings.append(str).append('\0');
  }
  Integer key_start = 7 * 4 + hash.size() * 4 * 4;
  Integer value_start = key_start + ids.length();

  Iterator e = offsets.iterator();
  while (e.hasNext()) {
    ArrayList<Integer> offEl = (ArrayList<Integer>) e.next();
    key_offsets.add(offEl.get(1));
    key_offsets.add(offEl.get(0) + key_start);
    value_offsets.add(offEl.get(3));
    value_offsets.add(offEl.get(2) + value_start);
  }

  temp_offsets.addAll(key_offsets);
  temp_offsets.addAll(value_offsets);


  os.writeByte(0xde);
  os.writeByte(0x12);
  os.writeByte(0x04);
  os.writeByte(0x95);

  os.writeByte(0x00);
  os.writeInt(hash.size() & 0xff);
  os.writeInt((7 * 4) & 0xff);
  os.writeInt((7 * 4 + hash.size() * 8) & 0xff);
  os.writeInt(0x00000000);
  os.writeInt(key_start & 0xff);

  Iterator offi = temp_offsets.iterator();
  while (offi.hasNext()) {
    Integer off = (Integer) offi.next();
    os.writeInt(off & 0xff);
  }
  os.writeUTF(ids.toString());
  os.writeUTF(strings.toString());

  os.close();
}
```

The line `os.writeInt(key_start);` seems like ok, the differences from the original tool generated mo file starting after theese bytes.

What's wrong? (aside from my scary english..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When comparing your implementation with the documentation I noticed two things:

1. <del>The revision, directly after the magic number, should be an int.</del> This seems to work, probably because `writeByte` outputs some padding. Using `writeInt` would be clearer however.
2. The `& 0xFF` part in the `writeInt` calls is probably wrong. This operation is needed to convert a signed byte to its unsigned integer value, for positive integers it should not be needed.

For parsing of the po files you could also have a look at the [zanata/tennera project on github](https://github.com/zanata/tennera).

**Edit:** The [writeUTF](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/DataOutput.html#writeUTF%28java.lang.String%29) call is also problematic since it prefixes the output with a two-byte length and mangles '\0' bytes using javas modified utf encoding. You could replace it by:

```
os.write(ids.toString().getBytes("utf-8"));
os.write(strings.toString().getBytes("utf-8"));
```

**Another Edit:** I could not let got of this code, there were further problems concerning string length in chars vs utf8 bytes and `DataOutputStream` writing in [big-endian instead of little endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). I think the following code should work, the difference is that the file produced by msgfmt contains an optional hashtable to speed up access:

```
public static void writeInt(OutputStream os, int i) throws IOException {
    os.write((i) & 0xFF);
    os.write((i >>> 8) & 0xFF);
    os.write((i >>> 16) & 0xFF);
    os.write((i >>> 24) & 0xFF);
}

public static void writeFile(String filename, TreeMap<String, String> polines) throws IOException {
    OutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filename));
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int size = polines.size();
    int[] indices = new int[size*2];
    int[] lengths = new int[size*2];
    int idx = 0;
    // write the strings and translations to a byte array and remember offsets and length in bytes
    for (String key : polines.keySet()) {
        byte[] utf = key.getBytes("utf-8");
        indices[idx] = bos.size();
        lengths[idx] = utf.length;
        bos.write(utf);
        bos.write(0);
        idx++;
    }
    for (String val : polines.values()) {
        byte[] utf = val.getBytes("utf-8");
        indices[idx] = bos.size();
        lengths[idx] = utf.length;
        bos.write(utf);
        bos.write(0);
        idx++;
    }

    try {
        int headerLength = 7*4;
        int tableLength = size*2*2*4;
        writeInt(os, 0x950412DE);                   // magic
        writeInt(os, 0);                            // file format revision
        writeInt(os, size);                         //number of strings
        writeInt(os, headerLength);                 // offset of table with original strings
        writeInt(os, headerLength + tableLength/2); // offset of table with translation strings
        writeInt(os, 0);                            // size of hashing table
        writeInt(os, headerLength + tableLength);   // offset of hashing table, not used since length is 0

        for (int i=0; i<size*2; i++) {
            writeInt(os, lengths[i]);
            writeInt(os, headerLength + tableLength + indices[i]);
        }

        // copy keys and translations
        bos.writeTo(os);

    } finally {
        os.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks the notices, but not helped. The signed/unsigned conversion not change the generated file, and the magic number part is ok, becuause the generated file and a real mo file header is exactly same.

When the generator work with simplified po files, I check the comlicated parser, but thanks.

Comment: Almost good. The header as fine, the differences started when writeing the hash table. [Compare files](http://i39.tinypic.com/20rln2d.png).

Comment: Can you post hexdumps of both versions as text? It might be easier to see the difference that way.

Comment: Yes. There is the a good file: [link](http://pastebin.com/KBzbhj1U)
  And this is the generated, it's not good: [link](http://pastebin.com/Lz0gsxrq)

Comment: Thank you, man! It's work! I've completely given up. :D So, this is the difference the newbie and a professional!